# How should I quote a book's name?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence

When writing, one often needs to quote the name of a book. How should I do it properly? I have met all of the following kinds of quotation. Which one is correct and what's the principle?

- *An Introduction to Manifolds*
- *AN INTRODUCTION TO MANIFOLDS*
- *an Introduction to Manifolds*
- *An introduction to manifolds*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you follow *The Chicago Manual of Style*, then publication titles are in *italics*, with the first letter of each word capitalized.

Short words inside the title such as *a*, *of*, *the*, *or* etc, or prepositions stay un-capitalized, regardless of length, *unless* they are part of an official name in the book title.

Examples:

*The Basset of Bakersville Cove*

*Ringside Seat at the Murder*

*Of Mice and Men*

Comment: How do you define "short words"?

Answer (score -1):

You should reproduce the capitalisation used in the book's title.

Comment: -1: The book's title may easily be in *ALL CAPITALS,* and I would never use *ALL CAPITALS* when quoting a book title. Even worse, I expect some books have titles which are typeset like *FIRE and BLOOD,* and different editions may be typeset differently; cover designers feel no compunction for consistency in typesetting.

Comment: @Peter: +1. I agree with you and appreciate you comment.